# Approximating the value of Pi using itertools and Leibniz series

Tags: python

Write a program that approximates the value of ππ by summing the terms of this series:

```
(4/1) - (4/3) + (4/5) - (4/7) + (4/9) - (4/11) + ……
```

What is wrong with this code

```
def main():
    n=eval(input("Enter N: "))
    x,y=0,0
    for i,j in itertools.product ((1,1+4*round((n//2)),4),(-3,-3-4*int((n/2)),-4)):
        x=x+(4/i)
        y=y+(4/j)
    print(x+y)
```

Comment: you tell us - what did you expect it to do, what does it do, what did you debug what might be the cause? (beside missing things like imports to qualify as [mre])

Comment: Could you please write the numbers in a way that the formula looks correct? As it's now, this looks like you want to do (1-4) and (3+4)

Comment: btw: `round((n//2))` ... integer division already gives you an integer - why round it?

Answer (score 3):

> What is wrong with this code?

A lot:

- Readability: it has no explanation of what its purpose is
- Usability: the user has to enter N without knowing what it's good for
- Maintainability: the for loop has half a dozen of constants, known as "magic numbers" without any explanation
- Readability: the Leibniz series is really simple. Why is the code so complex?
- Correctness: you implement `main()` but never call it.
- Security: `eval()` is dangerous

To address those issues:

- add a comment, what the code does, where the formula is described etc.
- Improve the question for user input
- Get rid of the complex code and implement a simple summation algorithm
- Use the formula as close as possible to avoid any confusion. The `4*` is already a stretch
- Use `int()` instead of `eval()` to get a number from the user input

Suggested result:

```
# Approximation of Pi using the Leibniz series
# See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80
# k is used as described on Wikipedia
# n is the number of approximation steps. n → ∞ to get close approximations

n = int(input("Enter the number of approximation steps:"))
pi = 0
for k in range(0, n):
    pi +=  4* (-1)**k / (2*k+1)
print(pi)
```

With 10.000.000 steps, it gives 3.141592<sub>55</sub>, so you really need large numbers of N.

---

Using `fractions` as suggested by @Patrick Artner is a good idea if you want to go for precision of the output. But it really slows down the calculations. Here's a comparison:

```
N      | FP                   | Fractions            | Diff
-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------
10000  | 3.1414926535900 345  | 3.1414926535900 434  | + 89E-16
20000  | 3.141542653589824 8  | 3.141542653589824 3  | -  5E-16
30000  | 3.14155932025646 20  | 3.14155932025646 93  | + 73E-16
40000  | 3.14156765358979 85  | 3.14156765358979 70  | - 15E-16
50000  | 3.1415726535897 814  | 3.1415726535897 950  | +136E-16
60000  | 3.1415759869231 020  | 3.1415759869231 277  | +257E-16
70000  | 3.141578367875 4820  | 3.141578367875 5083  | +263E-16
80000  | 3.1415801535897 496  | 3.1415801535897 936  | +440E-16
90000  | 3.1415815424786 238  | 3.1415815424786 824  | +586E-16
100000 | 3.1415826535897 198  | 3.1415826535897 935  | +740E-16
110000 | 3.141583562680 6436  | 3.141583562680 7027  | +591E-16
```

Comment: mhh .. do I bother to evaluate how much difference float-rounding vs fraction module make ... I guess ... later. Nice one :)

Comment: @PatrickArtner: probably later. I doubt OP has that level of knowledge. With 10.000.000 steps, it gives 3.14159255, which might be sufficient to tell that it goes to Pi.

Comment: @PatrickArtner: this fraction thing is strange. Why does the difference go up and down? I don't get it.

Comment: As soon as you "cast" the fraction back into floating it will have the same limitations as normal floats resolution wise. The advantage is that you do not accumulate the error by summing thousands of "off" floats. Maybe the errors in the floating numbers when summing somehow cancel each other out, dunno. more interesting then the diff towards each other should be the diff towards a precalculated pi and my guess would be that the fraction method should make a tighter fit to that error wise then using floats.

Answer (score 1):

Floating math and rounding will <strike>break your neck</strike> reduce the quality of your approximation.

You can use the [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module:

```
import fractions


while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("Amount of terms used for estimation of pi by Leibniz series: "))
        if n > 0:
            break
    except ValueError:
      print("Try again and be sensible about your inputs.")

sign = 1
pi = fractions.Fraction(0,1)
for nn in range(n):
    term = fractions.Fraction(sign * 4, 2*nn + 1)
    print(f"Approx nr: {nn+1})   pi before: {str(pi):>20}         approx refinement: {('+' if sign > 0 else '') + str(term):>20}", end="")
    pi += term
    print(f"   new pi:{pi} ({float(pi):2.8})")
    sign *= -1

print(float(pi))
```

To get (input 9):

```
Approx nr: 1)   pi before:                    0         approx refinement:                   +4   new pi:4 (4.0)
Approx nr: 2)   pi before:                    4         approx refinement:                 -4/3   new pi:8/3 (2.6666667)
Approx nr: 3)   pi before:                  8/3         approx refinement:                 +4/5   new pi:52/15 (3.4666667)
Approx nr: 4)   pi before:                52/15         approx refinement:                 -4/7   new pi:304/105 (2.8952381)
Approx nr: 5)   pi before:              304/105         approx refinement:                 +4/9   new pi:1052/315 (3.3396825)
Approx nr: 6)   pi before:             1052/315         approx refinement:                -4/11   new pi:10312/3465 (2.9760462)
Approx nr: 7)   pi before:           10312/3465         approx refinement:                +4/13   new pi:147916/45045 (3.2837385)
Approx nr: 8)   pi before:         147916/45045         approx refinement:                -4/15   new pi:135904/45045 (3.0170718)
Approx nr: 9)   pi before:         135904/45045         approx refinement:                +4/17   new pi:2490548/765765 (3.2523659)
3.252365934718876
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend to use `zip` and `range`, not `itertools.product`, which is going to create a sequence of pairs for each combination of the two sequences you provide.

For example,

- product((1,2),(3,4)) yields (1,3), (1,4), (2,3) and (2,4)
- whereas zip((1,2),(3,4)) yields (1,3) and (2,4), matching places one by one like a zip.

The corrected code is below, some comments are also helpful:

```
def main():
    n=eval(input("Enter N: "))
    x,y=0,0
    for i,j in zip(range(1,1+4*round((n//2)),4), range(-3,-3-4*int((n/2)),-4)):
        x=x+(4/i) # sum of positive parts
        y=y+(4/j) # sum of negative parts
    print(x+y)
```